Restrict Account Record Access
Setup:
The OWD is Read/Private
Profile has CRE access to Account object
Question: how can I restrict a profile to access an account record if the value of the status field is Open.
Status = Open (profile should not be able to view the records)
Status = close (profile should view the records)
Thank you

Have you looked at the documentation and the many tutorials on sharing rules, like this one?
